# How do I put a file in a custom location inside my application bundle?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, xcode4, bundle, quicklook

I need to put a plugin (specifically a QuickLook plugin) in /Contents/Library/QuickLook in my app bundle.

This is easy to do in Finder by clicking ***Show Package Contents*** and so forth, but I would like Xcode to do this every time I build my app.

How would I accomplish this? (Xcode 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a new Copy Files Build Task to your target, as described by MarkPowell in his answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1710167/3009).